# Show AJAX Response file into View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

My jquery AJAX is::

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'GetFile',
    date:data,
    success:function(response){
        //How to use the responded file?
    }
})
```

and on Server side I am returning the File as ::

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
     ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
     Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);  
     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");               
}
```

Here, I am returning the File from Server Side That I want to show into my View.

Mean to say, I just want to append the responded file to

```
 <div id="FileContent"></div>
```

which is into my view.

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display  a   PDF inside a div.

Give this a try:

```
<div id="FileContent">
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="800">
    </object>
</div>
```

set the `<object>`'s data property inside your #FileContent div using jquery on success of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple soluction.
Instead of returning the file just write the stream in to Response.

```
byte[] tempArrary = memoryStream.ToArray();
Response.BinaryWrite(tempArrary);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.End();
```

Then just return some Json result instead of File.

Add iframe insted of your DIV.

then set the src of the iframe to your controller using jquery.

```
$("#your_iframe").attr("src", "your_path");
```

If you want to use object or Embed tag instead of iframe then you have to create element for object or embed and the do the same